# Handling SMS permissions on android for auto verifying OTP

Tags: android, permissions

I am developing an android app, in which i require user to verify himself for the first time using sms based verification. In this user gives me his mobile number and i send him an OTP, which he can enter and verifies himself.

As soon as user enters the mobile, i read his SMS and on getting the desired SMS i extract OTP and automatically verify him. Now in order to do in newer android permissions model, i have to ask to user to give me SMS permissions. So i have following two part questing.

1) When should i ask for those permissions. For ex: if i ask him after he enters his mobile number, then let's say user accepts the permissions after the sms came, then it is of no use. If i ask him upfront when he comes to my app he might not understand the context why i need that permission.

2) Should i really auto verify the user or the better UX is to stay away from asking SMS permissions and let the user enter his OTP manually ?

Answer (score 2):

You can ask for permission when User reaches SMS screen and then:

1. If he accepts, read text and Auto verify.
2. If rejects, prompt him to Enter it manually.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Point is if the user accepts the permission after the sms arrives, it is of no use then.

Comment: Make API call to receive SMS only after he Accepts or Rejects.

Comment: Two options:
1) If is show him before he fills his mobile number and clicks on submit, the permissions are upfront like popup will open as soon as he opens app.

Comment: 1. Let user user Enter phone number
2. Prompt for permission
3. Make API call

What is tough to Understand bro?

Answer (score 0):

When user enter mobile number and tap on submit button then ask him for permission and after user selection, request server for OTP (inside onRequestPermissionResult).